# Clustering by values in columns

Tags: numpy, grouping, cluster-analysis

I have a text file with tab separated columns.

```
817619994   0.0 2369858 2369019
817619994   0.0 652427  651270
817619994   1e-117  2369858 2369019
817619994   1e-124  652427  651294
817619994   1e-147  2369858 2369019
817619994   1e-148  2369858 2369019
817619994   1e-158  2369858 2369019
817619994   1e-159  2369858 2369019
817619994   3e-118  652427  651291
817619994   3e-159  2369858 2369019
817619994   3e-94   652427  651291
817619994   4e-159  2369858 2369019
817619994   5e-118  652427  651291
817619994   6e-147  2369858 2369019
```

I want to assign an ID to each row based on the closeness of values in the final two columns, 3 and 4. I would like to use a cut off of 600. The resulting text file would look like this:

```
817619994   0.0 2369858 2369019 1
817619994   0.0 652427  651270  2
817619994   1e-117  2369858 2369019 1
817619994   1e-124  652427  651294  2
817619994   1e-147  2369858 2369019 1
817619994   1e-148  2369858 2369019 1
817619994   1e-158  2369858 2369019 1
817619994   1e-159  2369858 2369019 1
817619994   3e-118  652427  651291  2
817619994   3e-159  2369858 2369019 1
817619994   3e-94   652427  651291  2
817619994   4e-159  2369858 2369019 1
817619994   5e-118  652427  651291  2
817619994   6e-147  2369858 2369019 1
```

A less convoluted approach, if there is one, would be appreciated, but I have begun along the following lines, of comparing all values in one column with all other values in the same column:

I have constructed a difference array for columns 3 and 4 using numpy. Array3 for example shows the absolute difference between every value in column 3 with every other value in column 3 (26 by 26 array). Array4 is the same but for column 4.

```
$ python
>>>import numpy as np
>>>col3, col4 = np.loadtxt('test.txt', usecols=(2,3), unpack=True)
>>>A = col3
>>>B = col3
>>>Array3 = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(A, B))
```

(note in numpy fields begin counting at 0)

Beginning at row 1, which can be arbitrarily assigned to group 1, I now hope to assign each row a group id of 1,2,3 etc. based on the values in Array3 and Array4
(e.g. if Array3[x,1]<600 && Array4[x,1]<600, this line is group 1, where 600 is the cut off).

I assume this would find rows belonging to group 1, if I could script it. The other rows would be left blank in new column 5.

I then have the problem of finding group 2, 3 etc.

It could be that the first line encountered not satisfying the same-group criteria is assigned to group 2, and this group used as the search for group 2 members, ignoring those already assigned to a group (1). And the same for following groups (although in this example there are only 2 groups).

Comment: `sort -u` is more efficient than `sort | uniq`...

Comment: Your problem is *underspecified*. What about transitivity? Essentially, what you describe sounds like hierarchical clustering with a fixed threshold of 500 to me, and with the nonstandard "minimum" distance.

Comment: Thank you Anony-Mousse. I have added some detail and described what I am now trying with numpy, looking at the differences between values in the two columns I'm interested in. If this looks like hierarchical clustering then any details on this would be great - I have some rudimentary experience clustering in R but I don't have enough experience to go down this route yet.

Comment: based on which criteria you you judge the closeness between columns? do you know the number of cluster?